# FactoryGirl and RSpec: create a record with required nested_attributes for specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a model `contact` that `has_many :locations, through: :relationships`, as well as `has_many :teams, through: :contacts_teams`.

A contact **must** have an associated `team` and `location` in order to pass validations.  In other words: a new `contact` must have an associated `relationship` record and an associated `contacts_team` record.  Below are the models:

```
#models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :contacts

  has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :locations, through: :relationships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts_teams, allow_destroy: true

  # upon create, validate that at least one associated team and one associated location exist
  validate :at_least_one_contacts_team
  validate :at_least_one_relationship

  private

  def at_least_one_contacts_team
    return errors.add :base, "Must have at least one Team" unless contacts_teams.length > 0
  end

  def at_least_one_relationship
    return errors.add :base, "Must have at least one Location" unless relationships.length > 0
  end
end

#models/contacts_team.rb
class ContactsTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :team
end

#models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts_teams
  has_many :contacts, through: :contacts_teams
end

#models/relationship.rb
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :location
end

#models/location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :contacts, through: :relationships
end
```

For testing: with [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) I want to create a `contact` factory that is able to successfully create a `contact` record.  Since each `contact` record requires an associated `contacts_team` record and `relationship` record: when I create the `contact` record is should create those as well.  Likewise: the `contacts_team` record should have an existing `team` it is associated to, and the `relation` record should have an existing `location` it is associated to.  So essentially it should create a `location` and a `team` record as well.

**How can I create a contact record with a factory, which in effect creates an associated `contacts_team` record and a `relationship` record?**

Here are my current factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do
    first_name "Homer"
    last_name "Simpson"
    title "Nuclear Saftey Inspector"
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contacts_team do
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :team do
    name "Safety Inspection Team"
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :relationship do
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :location do
    name "Safety Location"
  end
end
```

If it is difficult/not possible to do this with factory_girl: how can I do it with straight rspec?  The issue is that I can't create a `contacts_team` record or a `relationship` record, because the `contact` it is associated to doesn't exist yet!  And I can't create a `contact` record because an associated `contacts_team` record or a `relationship` record doesn't exist yet.  It seems like I'm trapped, but there has to be a way to do this that is not sloppy.

Comment: can you please share your factories?

Comment: there is a way to call a factory upon completion of a previous factory

Comment: @NoamHacker sure let me get those.

Comment: @NoamHacker added them.  The tough part is that the `contact` record won't be created without an associated `contacts_team` or `relationship` record.  And the `contacts_team` or `relationship` records should not be created without an associated `contact`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer.  We need to build the associated records (the `contacts_team` record and the `relationship` record) and then we save all records at the exact same time to the database (just like how nested attributes get saved by rails):

```
#factories/contact.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do
    first_name "Homer"
    last_name "Simpson"
    title "Nuclear Saftey Inspector"
    agency
    contacts_teams {build_list :contacts_team, 1 }
    relationships {build_list :relationship, 1 }
  end
end

#factories/contacts_teams.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contacts_team do
    team
  end
end

#factories/teams.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :team do
    name "Safety Inspection Team"
  end
end

#factories/relationships.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :relationship do
    location
  end
end

#factories/locations.rb  
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :location do
    name "Safety Location"
  end
end
```

Then all you need to do is this:

```
create(:contact)
```

And with that it all at once creates a `contact` record, a `team` record, a `location` record, the associated `contacts_team` record, and the associated `relationship` record.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar requirement last week.

At the end of your factory, you can call the next factory, and they will then be related. For example:

/spec/factories/contacts.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :contact do |c|
        first_name "Homer"
        last_name "Simpson"
        title "Nuclear Saftey Inspector"

        # now, call the other two factories
        relationship
        contacts_team
    end


    factory :contacts_team do
        # call the team factory
        team
    end


    factory :relationship do
        # call the location factory
        location
    end


    # define the team and location factories...

end
```

Now, in /spec/controllers/contacts_controller_spec.rb

```
contact = FactoryGirl.create(:contact)
```

You can just use factory girl to create a contact, even if you just need, for example, a location, because everything will be generated at once.

**ALTERNATIVE (rspec)**

don't "chain" your factories, instead in /spec/controllers/contacts_controller_spec.rb

```
contact = FactoryGirl.create(:contact)
# use .create_list(model, number, parent) to make children of a specific parent
contacts_team = FactoryGirl.create_list(:contacts_team, 3, :contact => contact)
relationship = FactoryGirl.create_list(:relationship, 3, :contact => contact)
team = FactoryGirl.create_list(:team, 3, :contacts_team => contacts_team)
location = FactoryGirl.create_list(:location, 3, :relationship => relationship)
```

This will create a contact, with 3 contact_teams (with 3 teams), and with 3 relationships (with 3 locations)

Hope this helps you figure out the correct pattern to make your test data :)

Comment: Makes sense.   Trying it out now.

Comment: There is no `contacts_team_id` or `relationship_id` column on the `contacts` table because those are `has_many` associations (otherwise I think this would work).  So it seems like currently this gets me closer but isn't working right now.

Comment: sorry for the many edits, I fixed a few things (you can actually have all the factories in the one contacts.rb file)

Comment: you can also do the `has_many` relationships with rspec, I will update my answer now

Comment: @Neil see the alternative update and let me know if this helps you or if I misunderstood something

Comment: The issue is that `contact = FactoryGirl.create(:contact)` won't work because the `contact` record will fail validations without having an associated `contacts_team` and `relationship`.  They all have to be done simultaneously just like if you were creating a record with nested attributes.

Comment: I see, not sure about this one yet but i'll keep looking

Comment: Wow, that is almost my exact situation. Only difference is I have two required nested attributes whereas this example just has one.  Great find!  I'll try it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can do it multiple ways. But one way that's often been advised is to use the FactoryGirl `after(:create)` or `after(:build)`. In your case if you have the factory for all your models, you can easily call:

`after(:create) do |team, evaluator|
    create_list(:contact_team, 5, team: team)
 end`

Based on the documentation, after(:create) yields the team and the evaluator, which stores all values from the factory, including transient attributes

This would create 5 contact_teams associated with the team for you. For each factory if you define all the relationships like this, you would have your full associations defined. The alternative would be to follow Noam's suggestion, which is also good, but has its own limits.
You can find more information here: [FactoryGirl Associations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I did notice that `after(:create`) but it wasn't working for me.  It comes back with this error: `Validation failed: Must have at least one Team, Must have at least one Location`.  Basically: It is failing because I think it first tries to create the `contact`, and then it tries to create the `contacts_team` and the `relationship` records which doesn't work.  They need to be created simultaneously instead of one after the other.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: That makes sense. In that case, you could use the `after(:build)` and use the `build_list` method instead of `create_list`. In your test you should be able to run `create(:team)` and it should work

Comment: I think I'm close!  I did: `after(build) do |cc, evaluator| create_list(:contacts_team, 2, contact_id: cc.id) end`  The issue is that it does not appear it is assigning the created contact's id to the `contacts_team` records because `cc.id` is nil.  Any tips?  Thanks again for your help so far.

Comment: how about using `build_list(:contacts_team, 2, team: cc)`. I'm happy to hear you;re getting closer.

Comment: it is properly assigning the `team_id` to the `contacts_team` record.  The `contact_id` is the issue, but I'll try that one quick.

Comment: It says: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Team(#123) expected, got Contact(#456)`

Comment: oh! do you have a `contact` factory? you could actually use something like `build_list(:contacts_team, 2, contact: build(:contact))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107269/discussion-between-neil-and-user49208).